# e4 application custom icons showing as red square

Tags: eclipse, icons, perspective, e4

I have an eclipse 4 application and i'm having issues using custom icons for perspectives and other contributions.

In the .e4xmi application editor the icon shows as a red box. It doesn't show up in the running application either.

My icon uri is platform:/plugin/org.jim.g3.iec61131.il.e4.product/icons/jimElectric_16.png and the icon is 16x16 and opens correctly in an image viewer.

I can use the icons okay in an e3.x application and set up perspectives in that way instead. I would like to use e4 though.

If I use another icon uri from an eclipse icon it works. e.g. platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources//icons/full/eview16/resource_persp.gif

So I guess there is something I need to do to the icon URI, icon itself or project setup? Thanks for any help.

The full Application.e4xmi is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<application:Application xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:advanced="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/ui/advanced" xmlns:application="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application" xmlns:basic="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/ui/basic" xmlns:menu="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/ui/menu" xmi:id="_VnmacNSzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA" elementId="org.jim.g3.language.il.e4.product.application" bindingContexts="_VnmacdSzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA">
  <children xsi:type="basic:TrimmedWindow" xmi:id="_Vnmah9SzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA" label="My Main Window" iconURI="" width="800" height="600">
    <children xsi:type="advanced:PerspectiveStack" xmi:id="_Vnmaj9SzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA" selectedElement="_VnmakNSzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA">
      <children xsi:type="advanced:Perspective" xmi:id="_VnmakNSzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA" elementId="test.rcp.perspective" label="Intro" iconURI="platform:/plugin/org.jim.g3.language.il.e4.product/icons/jimElectric_16.png">
        <tags>Perspective</tags>
        <tags>categoryTag:General</tags>
        <children xsi:type="basic:Part" xmi:id="_WoxEsCr-EeWMqfhe61ykdA" elementId="org.jim.g3.language.il.e4.product.introview" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.jim.g3.language.il.e4.product/org.jim.g3.language.il.e4.product.IntroView" label="Intro" iconURI=""/>
      </children>
    </children>
    <sharedElements xsi:type="advanced:Area" xmi:id="_Hmg4kNSjEeGwXp2p959l3w" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.editorss">
      <children xsi:type="basic:PartStack" xmi:id="_HmhfoNSjEeGwXp2p959l3w" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.primaryDataStack">
        <tags>newtablook</tags>
        <tags>org.eclipse.e4.primaryDataStack</tags>
        <tags>EditorStack</tags>
      </children>
    </sharedElements>
    <sharedElements xsi:type="basic:Part" xmi:id="_WqRGcNS1EeGBn6dQ9VPexA" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.views.PropertySheet" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView" label="Properties" iconURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.views//icons/full/eview16/prop_ps.gif" closeable="true">
      <tags>View</tags>
      <tags>categoryTag:General</tags>
      <menus xmi:id="_HngXENSjEeGwXp2p959l3w" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.views.PropertySheet">
        <tags>ViewMenu</tags>
        <tags>menuContribution:menu</tags>
      </menus>
      <toolbar xmi:id="_Hng-INSjEeGwXp2p959l3w" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.views.PropertySheet"/>
    </sharedElements>
    <sharedElements xsi:type="basic:Part" xmi:id="_sS7Q8NS1EeGBn6dQ9VPexA" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView" label="Project Explorer" iconURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources//icons/full/eview16/resource_persp.gif">
      <tags>View</tags>
      <tags>categoryTag:General</tags>
      <menus xmi:id="_4UXAUNSmEeG-a6zBTyJ-wg" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer">
        <tags>ViewMenu</tags>
        <tags>menuContribution:menu</tags>
      </menus>
      <menus xsi:type="menu:PopupMenu" xmi:id="_4VpZwNSmEeG-a6zBTyJ-wg" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu">
        <tags>menuContribution:popup</tags>
        <tags>popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu</tags>
      </menus>
      <toolbar xmi:id="_4UXAUdSmEeG-a6zBTyJ-wg" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer"/>
    </sharedElements>
    <trimBars xmi:id="_VOV6ANTAEeGTY-uOtVc6Mg" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar"/>
    <trimBars xmi:id="_VP1HwNTAEeGTY-uOtVc6Mg" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.trim.status" side="Bottom"/>
  </children>
  <bindingTables xmi:id="_VnmafNSzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA" bindingContext="_VnmacdSzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA"/>
  <rootContext xmi:id="_VnmacdSzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow" name="In Dialog and Windows">
    <children xmi:id="_VnmactSzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window" name="In Windows"/>
    <children xmi:id="_Vnmac9SzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialog" name="In Dialogs"/>
  </rootContext>
  <descriptors xmi:id="_9E9jYNS4EeGBn6dQ9VPexA" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer" label="Project Explorer" iconURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources//icons/full/eview16/resource_persp.gif" category="org.eclipse.e4.primaryNavigationStack" closeable="true" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView">
    <tags>View</tags>
    <tags>categoryTag:General</tags>
  </descriptors>
  <descriptors xmi:id="_W6yT4NSjEeGgKvWHVYtRxQ" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView" label="Console" iconURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.console//icons/full/cview16/console_view.gif" allowMultiple="true" category="org.eclipse.e4.secondaryDataStack" closeable="true" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView">
    <tags>View</tags>
    <tags>categoryTag:General</tags>
  </descriptors>
  <descriptors xmi:id="_W6ziANSjEeGgKvWHVYtRxQ" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.views.ProgressView" label="Progress" iconURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.ide//icons/full/eview16/pview.gif" category="org.eclipse.e4.secondaryDataStack" closeable="true" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView">
    <tags>View</tags>
    <tags>categoryTag:General</tags>
  </descriptors>
  <descriptors xmi:id="_W63zcdSjEeGgKvWHVYtRxQ" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.views.PropertySheet" label="Properties" iconURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.views//icons/full/eview16/prop_ps.gif" allowMultiple="true" category="org.eclipse.e4.secondaryDataStack" closeable="true" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView">
    <tags>View</tags>
    <tags>categoryTag:General</tags>
  </descriptors>
  <toolBarContributions xmi:id="_AEBdYCn2EeWFOq2j27wvQQ" elementId="org.jim.g3.language.il.e4.product.toolbarcontribution.0">
    <children xsi:type="menu:ToolControl" xmi:id="_FhkrMCn2EeWFOq2j27wvQQ" elementId="org.jim.g3.language.il.e4.product.toolcontrol.0" contributionURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt/org. eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.perspectiveswitcher.PerspectiveSwitcher"/>
  </toolBarContributions>
  <addons xmi:id="_VnmadNSzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.service" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.core.commands/org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.CommandServiceAddon"/>
  <addons xmi:id="_VnmaddSzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.ui.contexts.service" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.services/org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.ContextServiceAddon"/>
  <addons xmi:id="_VnmadtSzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.service" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings/org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.BindingServiceAddon"/>
  <addons xmi:id="_Vnmad9SzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.commands.model" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.CommandProcessingAddon"/>
  <addons xmi:id="_VnmaeNSzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.contexts.model" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.ContextProcessingAddon"/>
  <addons xmi:id="_VnmaedSzEeGBn6dQ9VPexA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.bindings.model" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon"/>
</application:Application>
```

Comment: Also when I hover over the Icon URI, the icon shows as a tooltip. So my URI must be correct right?

Comment: Is the icons directory listed in the 'build.properties' file?

Comment: Hi greg, yes it is. `output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               Application.e4xmi,\
               icons/
source.. = src/,\
src.includes = icons/'`

Comment: Just to add that I am using eclipse mars, I have also tried luna and it has the same issue. In Mars I have Eclipse E4 tools 4.5.0v2015 installed

Comment: Does it show up when you click the 'Find...' button next to the 'iconURI' field in the editor?

Comment: yes it does and I can even see a preview of the icon

Comment: Just guessing but try starting with the -clean and -clearPersistedState options to make sure caches and state are rebuilt.

Comment: I just added -clean and -clearPersistedState options but no luck.

Comment: fyi, the red square is in the .e4xmi editor however when I run the application the default icon is used (not red square).

Comment: @ChrisColes, I have exactly the same problem. I tried adding only -clearPersistedState as suggested here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=467621 and it worked fine.